# How to safely uninstall Voyager in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, voyager

After update Laravel to 5.8.* Voyager is completely broken

Suddenly BREADS are broken, searchable is

> Undefined variable
>
> Call to a member function getTranslatedAttribute() on null

appears every time...

I am thinking about completely uninstall Voyager for good.

How do I uninstall it? Any hints, please?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Voyager entangles itself in the Laravel application so simply doing

```sh
composer remove tcg/voyager
```

may not be enough

- remove larapack hooks repository from `composer.json`

```
"repositories": {
        "hooks": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://larapack.io"
        }
    }
```

Also delete the `hooks` directory on the root of your project

- remove voyager routes from `routes/web.php`

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Voyager::routes();
});
```

- Remove Package information from config (if added)

File: config/app.php
comment or delete following lines.

```
/*
 * Package Service Providers...
 */
TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::class,
```

- Let the user model extends `Auth\User` instead of Voyager's user

From this

```php
class User extends \TCG\Voyager\Models\User
```

To this

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
```

- delete voyager config from `config/voyager.php`
- remove voyager migrations from `database/migrations`

```
2016_01_01_000000_create_pages_table.php
2016_01_01_000000_create_posts_table.php
2016_02_15_204651_create_categories_table.php
2017_04_11_000000_alter_post_nullable_fields_table.php
```

- remove database seeders from `database/seeds`

```
CategoriesTableSeeder.php
DataRowsTableSeeder.php
DataTypesTableSeeder.php
MenuItemsTableSeeder.php
MenusTableSeeder.php
PagesTableSeeder.php
PermissionRoleTableSeeder.php
PermissionsTableSeeder.php
PostsTableSeeder.php
RolesTableSeeder.php
SettingsTableSeeder.php
TranslationsTableSeeder.php
UsersTableSeeder.php
VoyagerDatabaseSeeder.php
VoyagerDummyDatabaseSeeder.php
```

- And finally remove `public/vendor/tcg` folder to remove static assets

Comment: I think I found the bug.
This error runs when setting server-side pagination.

Comment: Yep that messes things up. The listings won't work anymore with large numbers of users. If you still want to get rid of Voyager entirely don't forget to delete the corresponding database tables as well.

Comment: didnt need to remove Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider????

Comment: That's not necessarily related to Voyager, it's a different package for image manipulation

Comment: For the migrations, if you already ran them, it's probably best to just write new ones with "dropIfExists" to remove those tables. Simply deleting the files won't be enough.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest never upgrade an existing project without preparation.

1. Back-up your code (GIT is great)
2. Back-up your database to reverse, if something gets broken.
3. Repeat this also when upgrading a Drupal or WordPress website

To uninstall you need:

```
composer remove tcg/voyager
```

Also remove the routes from your routes/web.php