# ReflectionException (-1) Class VoyagerAuth does not exist - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, voyager

I am working on a laravel app, and when I run `php artisan serve` I get this error:

```
 ReflectionException (-1)
Class VoyagerAuth does not exist
```

Comment: Please share more details, and your debugging attempts

Answer (score 1):

You might have installed [the-control-group/voyager](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager) and then deleted some file.
If you wish to use it try to run

```
composer install
```

or

```
composer update
```

if you don't want to use voyager uninstall it, there is an handy guide on an answer on this older [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58124293/how-to-safely-uninstall-voyager-in-laravel)